# Decode JSON (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, json, steam, steam-web-api

how can I select the number of "total_items" and the "average_price"?

JSON:

```
   {
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "items" : [
      {
        "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)",
        "total_items" : 698,
        "lowest_price" : "3.90",
        "highest_price" : "300.00",
        "cumulative_price" : "4669.62",
        "recent_sales_info" : {
          "hours" : "17.94",
          "average_price" : "4.23"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thats my PHP-Script:

```
$link = 'skin.json';
    $string = file_get_contents($link);
    $obj = json_decode($string, TRUE);
$name = $obj['items']['market_hash_name'];
$itmes = $name['total_items'];
$itmes = $name['average_price'];
```

How can I save the number of "total_items" and the "average_price" in variables?
Thank You
Regards.
Enge

Comment: It seems that you'd access `$obj['data']['items'][0]['total_items']` and `$obj['data']['items'][0]['recent_sales_info']['average_price']`.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Andreas wrote, or :

```
// first, new variable (shorter lines/less depth afterwards)
$article = $obj['data']['items'][0];

// then 
$total_items = $article['total_items'];
$avg_price = $article['recent_sales_info']['average_price'];
```

Enge, note that "items": **[** is an opening array within JSON object, that's the zero You were missing...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$total_items = $obj['data']['items'][0]['total_items'];
$avg_price = $obj['data']['items'][0]['recent_sales_info']['average_price'];
```

Comment: A little bit off-topic, but that last name of yours, is it common? Had a lecturer with the same last name once.

Comment: Is that right?: $link = 'skin.json';
   $string = file_get_contents($link);
    $obj = json_decode($string, TRUE);
$total_items = $obj['data']['items'][0]['total_items'];
$avg_price = $obj['data']['items'][0]['recent_sales_info']['average_price'];
echo $total_items;
echo $avg_price;

Comment: @Enge Yes. You could echo it in an array instead, depending on the context